# make facebook page tab application to use HTTP GET verb

Tags: facebook, web

I am building an application in the RESTful manner,All I want is to integrate it as Facebook page tab.
The problem arises that  facebok Sends POST verb to get the main page which I only allowed GET on it.
is there anyway to make facebook send GET verb to my Application instead of POST
Note: I use laravel if it does matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the answer is no :)

Facebook sends POST request with **signed_request** data.

Comment: So What's the idea behind that ?

Comment: don't know, ask facebook ;) signed_request contains multiple useful informations like "if user liked page" or "if he agreed for permissions" for given facebook app, so using that you can get this information as soon as user hit's the page. don't gave to make additional queries. can't imagine this data will be send via GET request

Comment: This things that facebook does maybe useful for others, not me !
Thanks dude